# Accessing a Local Shared library from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, shared-libraries

I have a local shared library (written in C) on a Linux system - I can call it from a C program with a string, it does a computation and returns a string result. I can also call it from Java using JNI/JNA.

Is there any way to call it from JavaScript in a webpage from a local browser (Firefox, or Chrome)?

Thanks for suggestions.

Cheers,
Sen

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't.

That would be a very serious security problem.

You must use an intermediate server (local or not) to do this call. Or you may develop a plugin but that won't be a cross-browser solution.

As you're yet using JNI/JNA to call this library, the simplest would be to make a [servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet)  to answer an [ajax request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Comment: Can you explain how this can be implemented using an intermediate server?

Comment: If I plan to write a plugin for my webkit browser, How can this be done? Any links which can guide me to write plugins for Webkit, which can be used from my JS?

Comment: I never wrote Chrome plugins (I wrote many Chrome extensions) but this page may interest you : http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html . For Safari (the other major WebKit browser, I really have no experience so I won't answer).

Comment: So if i write my native functions as an extension, is it possible to use it from my javascript?

Comment: No, extensions are very severely restricted in their possibilities (and they're more and more restricted). I you want a direct access without server, a plugin will be needed.